# Sliding box/menu with 3 options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a box with a title and 2 arrows left and right of the title. When you click on either arrow, the box should fade out and the next one should fade in. I have another one like this on my page with 2 option (send and go back) and that one works fine, but for some reason it breaks when I have 3 options. I suspect it's my jQuery code that breaks when adding a third option.

My [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bey1vht1/23/) (minimal CSS to avoid confusion, the problem isn't there)

```
$('#go2').click(function(e) {
  $('.box1, .box3').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('.box2').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});

$('#go3').click(function(e) {
  $('.box2, .box1').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('.box3').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});

$('#go1').click(function(e) {
  $('.box2, .box3').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('.box1').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDs must be unique (refer to **id="go2"**).

The jQuery library must be included before the other libs.

You can simplify everything using a unique handler:

```js
$('.box1, .box2, .box3').on('click', function(e) {
    var isArrowRight = $(e.target).is('.right');
    var isLeftArrow  = $(e.target).is('.left');
    if (!(isArrowRight || isLeftArrow)) {
        return; // do nothing if you don't click the left/right arrow...
    }
    var nextEle = (isArrowRight) ? $(this).next('[class^=box]') : $(this).prev('[class^=box]');
    if (nextEle.length == 0) {
        nextEle = (isArrowRight) ? $('.box1') : $('.box3');
    }
    $('.box1:visible, .box2:visible, .box3:visible').fadeOut('fast', function(){
        nextEle.fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
i {
    display: inline;
}

h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap..css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/components/icon.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.0/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1">
    <div class="boxTitle">
        <i id="go3" class="icon angle left"></i>
        <h1>Box 1</h1>
        <i id="go22" class="icon angle right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="boxField1">
        Boxfield 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box2" style="display: none">
    <div class="boxTitle">
        <i id="1" class="icon angle left"></i>
        <h1>Box 2</h1>
        <i id="3" class="icon angle right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="boxField2">
        Boxfield 2
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box3" style="display: none">
    <div class="boxTitle">
        <i id="go2" class="icon angle left"></i>
        <h1>Box 3</h1>
        <i id="go1" class="icon angle right"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="boxField3">
        Boxfield 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Even though your code is really clean, it defeated the purpose of the arrows left and right. Now every time you click on the box itself (.box1, .box2, .box3) it will fade into the next one. After I realized my 2 mistakes, I fixed it and now it looks like this, with the functionality I wanted: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bey1vht1/30/), but it has a lot of repetitive code in my js file, is there a way to make it more clean with your method, but by keeping the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but looking your jsfiddle file I see 2 problems:

1. you use the same id for more html tag, it's not possible try using class.
2. On the box2 you use id="1" and id="3" but on js you use go1, go2, go3.

Comment: Thanks. I realized the second mistake last night, but that doesn't fix the first problem of course.